# Raspberry pi:how to send data from uart to raspberry pi?

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi, putty

I want to send data from uart to raspberry pi 3. So i have add code in my program,but is is giving error like:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 453, in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size-len(read))
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

### This is my python script of capturing image when gpio button pressed and also send packet "75 01 01 06 00 08" to uart.

```
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import encoders
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import time
import smtplib
import serial

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=115200,timeout=3.0)
# Define these once; use them twice!
strFrom = 'example@gmail.com'
strTo = 'example@gmail.com'

#create email
# Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subj$
#msgRoot = MIMEMultipart()
#msgRoot['Subject'] = 'capture image'
#msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
#msgRoot['To'] = strTo

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
print "press button to send email"
def split(s, chunk_size):
    a = zip(*[s[i::chunk_size] for i in range(chunk_size)])
    return [''.join(t) for t in a]

while True:
        input=GPIO.input(4)
        if input == True:
                print "button pressed"
                a="0x750x010x010x060x000x08"
                b1=a.split("0x")
                b2=[int(x,16) for x in b1 if x]
                b=str(bytearray(b2))
                port.write(b)
                x=port.read(10)
                print x
                subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam","-r 640x480", "capture.jpg"])
                time.sleep(2)
                #create email
                # Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and
                # subj$
                msgRoot = MIMEMultipart()
                msgRoot['Subject'] = 'BCMaster1 Node1 detected intrusion'
                msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
                msgRoot['To'] = strTo
                # This example assumes the image is in the current
                # directory
                filename = "capture.jpg"
                fp = open("capture.jpg", "rb")
                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                part.set_payload((fp).read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "fp; filename= %s" % filename)
                msgRoot.attach(part)
                fp.close()
                # send mail
                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                s.starttls()
                s.login('example@gmail.com' , 'password')
                s.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, msgRoot.as_string())
                s.close()
                print "Email sent"
```

now i want when i send any value from terminal it is display that value on raspberry pi terminal but is givving error as above described.so how to solve this error in raspberry pi 3?.plz help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the __full__ code required to reproduce the problem and the __full__ error traceback to your question!

Comment: i have edited my question..i have add my code also...plz see and tell me the solution.

Comment: Check `/proc/cmdline` if it defines a console on the serial port. If it does you have to remove that from your bootloader configuration.

Comment: i dont have deep knowledge in raspberry pi...plz tell me how to check?

Comment: I think you question is better asked at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . There are the RaspberryPi people.